# Why isn't my filebeats if processor working?

Tags: filebeat, elastic-beats

Goal here is checking some conditions and replacing values. I'm working with an if processor for my filebeat (interacting with elasticsearch)

```
  - if:
      and:
        regexp:
          severity_for_condition: 1
          event_type_for_condition: "bat_vol"
    then:
      - add_fields:
          target: "data.condition"
          fields:
            data.condition: "Low voltage detected - critical"
    else:
      - add_fields:
          target: "data.condition"
          fields:
            data.condition: "Low voltage detected - warning"
  - if:
      and:
        regexp:
          severity_for_condition: 1
          event_title_for_condition: "GPS Power Loss"
    then:
      - add_fields:
          target: "data.condition"
          fields:
            data.condition: "GPS power loss detected"
    else:
      - add_fields:
          target: "data.condition"
          fields:
            data.condition: "Intermittent GPS power loss detected"
```

Error I'm getting is:

`error initializing beat: error initializing processors: failed to make if/then/else processor: missing or invalid condition`

Where is the missing or invalid condition? I'll add that those values in the
`regexp:` 
Are coming from my script above in the file:

```
 - script:
      lang: javascript
      source: >
        function process(event) {
          var severity_for_condition = event.Get("data.severity");
          var event_type_for_condition = event.Get("type");
          var event_title_for_condition = event.Get("data.title");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/defining-processors.html) says

```
and:
  - equals:
      http.response.code: 200
  - equals:
      status: OK
```

Therefore, try:

```
- if:
      and:
        regex:
          event_type_for_condition: "bat_vol"
        regexp:
          severity_for_condition: 1

    then:
      - add_fields:
          target: "data.condition"
          fields:
            data.condition: "Low voltage detected - critical"
```